# Diacritics / Umlauts via Applescript to do shell script

Tags: shell, curl, character-encoding, applescript, diacritics

In an Applescript I am trying to pass on a URL that I receive as an argument to a `do shell script` command to use it with curl.

With regular characters the procedure works fine, but as soon as my argument contains special characters like Umlauts, it gets all funky.

curl does download something, but replaces the letter Ü with Ã etc., which of course will not get me the correct result.

What do I need to do, to get this to work? I am neither very skilled with Applescript nor with encoding issues.

My setup at the moment is as follows:

```
set download_URL to item 1 of arguments
do shell script "curl " & download_URL & " > targetFile.html"
```

Some examples of what happens:

```
Äquivozität ---> ÃquivozitÃ¤t
Ökolikör ---> ÃkolikÃ¶r
Übermütigkeit ---> ÃbermÃ¼tigkeit
Schweißfuß ---> SchweiÃfuÃ
```

Which makes my confusion even greater. All Ä, Ö, Ü and ß render as Ã, but both in the editing mask here and in the one of the site in question they render as shown in this image.

[image: Umlaut rendering]

Also, through some amateurish digging in the html-File, I figured out that instead of the letter `Ü`, I would need to pass the letters `%C3%9C`. So the whole procedure does work, if I pass `%C3%9Cbermut` instead of `Übermut`. However, I would of course like to avoid creating a translation table for all diacritics.

Can somebody figure out, what specific encoding problem is happening here?

Comment: Can you provide some specific examples of the replacements?

Comment: @CraigSmith thanks for looking into it, I edited the post.

Comment: Have you tried (download_URL as Unicode text)?  I know that AppleScript is Unicode compliant, so really, if that code is needed, it should only need to be: (download_URL as text).  It's a longshot, but give it a try.

Comment: It's clearly an text encoding issue. Before writing pipe the output to `textutil` to convert the encoding.

Comment: Craig Smith, I tried that, but it produced the same result.
vadian, I didn't get that to work, but mainly because I didn't know which encoding to choose.
However, I have found a way that works for me and posted it as an answer. Feel free to improve it. Thank you both for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more researching, I found out that what I need to *urlEncode* my string. That way, the letter `Ü` will be replaced with `%C3%9C` and it works for my purposes.

Applescript does not seem to support this natively, but one can use php to do the conversion. I found the method here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/9801376#9801376

So, in my case I used it like this:

```
set keyword to item 1 of arguments

set encodedKeyword to do shell script "php -r 'echo trim(urlencode(" & "\"" & keyword & "" & "\"));'"

do shell script "curl https://www.myUrl.com/" & encodedKeyword & ".html > targetFile"
```

This way, it works for me.
In case there is a better way - maybe something that works in Applescript directly - feel free to post another answer, then I'll change the accepted answer.